# Configuration software and/or driver for the Zinnia Mt-100 tablet

Tags: drivers, graphics-tablet, digitalpen

I'm using this version of Ubuntu:

```
Command: lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

I have a Zinnia mt-100 digitized table, I would like to know if there is any software, driver or configuration for Ubuntu.
The problem is that the orientation of the stroke does not match the movement of the cursor. Ex: vertical pen move, horizontal cursor move, etc.

in the README of the table (it is recognized as a pendrive and there are drivers for Windows and MAC) it says that for Linux it does not need the drivers because it is 'plug and play' but it is working for me...

solution suggestions?

NOTE: The pressure works normally and the table itself works normally in windows